# Improve appearance of GTK apps in Plasma5 installed on top Ubuntu Gnome

Tags: gnome, kubuntu, kde

I've installed Ubuntu 18.04 then with tasksel, kubuntu-desktop full along with sddm.

Now most of the application in KDE look like this:

[image]

Plasma look on top and gnome border/colors below. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the look of certain applications that have a [GTK GUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GTK%2B) within the KDE/Plasma desktop which is a [Qt](https://www.qt.io/) desktop. You surely have a lot of GTK applications because you also have the Gnome desktop and Ubuntu Gnome is your first system, Gnome being a GTK desktop.

Main GTK desktops are: Gnome, Cinnamon, Mate, Xfce, Pantheon (elementary), Budgie. Qt desktops are fewer: most popular are KDE/Plasma and LXQt (of Lubuntu 18.10).

Main GTK applications (that are hard to avoid even in a Qt desktop) are: Firefox, Chrome, Audacious, Rhythmbox, Synaptic, Skype etc. Main Qt applications (that are popular on all desktops) are: VLC, SMPlayer, Audacity, Qmmp, K3b etc.

The **look of GTK applications within the KDE desktop** can be greatly improved though, even if a lot of them will keep their "Gnome" (GTK) look, by installing GTK themes that fit the KDE look. There is a Breeze GTK theme for example.

```
sudo apt install breeze-gtk-theme
```

Plasma 5 has an appearance setting for GTK/Gnome applications:

Go to *System Settings > Application style > Gnome Application Style* and there set your GTK2 and GTK3 themes (select Breeze etc).

Note that GTK apps that need administrator rights usually do not follow those settings (which seems to be the case with the gdebi application in your image).

---

Beside the GTK-specific aspects of this problem, there are some Gnome-specific problems of appearance. As described [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/08/how-to-disable-gtk3-client-side.html), *"Starting with GNOME 3.10, some GNOME applications have switched to "header bars" or "client-side decorations". These CSD (client-side decorations) don't work properly in some desktop environments"*. These can be disabled by simply installing the `gtk3-nocsd` package. You have to see if you need that or not. I haven't seen much change in Kubuntu after that (but I don't have a lot of Gnome-specific programs and maybe none that uses CSD); and, if you still want to use Gnome in parallel and keep those decorations, installing "nocsd" is not a good idea I imagine.

---

If you prefer KDE/Plasma to Gnome you should install Kubuntu from scratch if possible and thus avoid a lot of problems. Both Gnome and Plasma5 are heavy desktops that come with a lot of dependencies and possible compatibility problems.